# [__NSCFConstantString productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ac04'

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I used test user account for test my In App Purchase app. I used product names like `#define PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER @"com.companyname.appname.P1"` When i run my app in simulator i got following in Log:

YES u can make payments2013-04-22 11:37:44.809 appname[2382:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ac04

code:

```
    -(void)checkForPayments{
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {
            printf("\n YES u can make payments");
   //   SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER];
        SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER];
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];              
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   1. SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER]; // CORRECT
   2. SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER]; //WRONG
```

1. Is correct as your passing the PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER that is NSString, and it takes NSString
2. Is wrong because the parameter your passing is NSString, where as it requires `SKProduct` not `NSString`..

To use `SKProduct` you need to first get the products using `SKProductRequest` as below

```
SKProductsRequest *req = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER]];
req.delegate = self;
[req start];
```

Then in the `Delegate` of `SKProductRequest` you have to do following

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

      for(SKProduct *product in response.products){
            SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
      } 
}
```

Comment: paymentWithProductIdentifier is deprecated in ios5. What can i do?

Comment: You are correct. But when i use my test user account it displays your Apple Id is incorrect. But i used correct apple test Id.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are passing NSString to a function that takes object of some other type. That is the reason you get

```
-[__NSCFConstantString productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Check wether the inApp id you created on iTunes is matching with the inApp id you defined in the app. And make sure you associated the inApp with your app in iTunes.